# Can I write a computer program based on a theory in a borrowed book?

Tags: united-states, copyright, software

Suppose I borrow a book from a library and then use the theory described in this book to write a commercial computer program. In this situation, am I infringing any copyright laws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, Copyright does not extend to theories:

> Section 102 of the Copyright Act (title 17 of the U.S. Code) clearly
>   expresses this principle: “In no case does copyright protection for an
>   original work of authorship extend to any idea, procedure, process,
>   system, method of operation, concept, principle, or discovery,
>   regardless of the form in which it is described, explained,
>   illustrated, or embodied in such work.” [Copyright of Ideas, Methods, or Systems - govcirc31.pdf](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ31.pdf)

Copyright does protects the *expression* of a theory. In your case,

> A computer program is a set of statements or instructions to be used
>   directly or indirectly in a computer to bring about a certain result.
>   Copyright protection for a computer program extends to all of the
>   copyrightable expression embodied in the program. The copyright law
>   does not protect the functional aspects of a computer program, such as
>   the program’s algorithms, formatting, functions, logic, or system
>   design. [Copyright
>   Registration of Computer Programs - circ61.pdf](https://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ61.pdf)

So you can develop a commercial computer program that does what the theory postulates, and that program itself will be under your copyright.

The idea that you borrow the book from the library isn't relevant; nor would be reading the book in a bookstore.